# How can I check API version?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want use bluetooth low energy (BLE).
In `API` lower than 21 I should use `startlescan()` and in API 21 I should use `startscan()` and its scan callback that is not for API less than 21.

how can I separate those code to have both in my app?

The error:
[image]

I want something like this:

```
if(api < 21) startlescan();
if(api >= 21) startscan();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code:-

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    startlescan();
}
else{

    startscan();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    // Run code where min API level is 21
} else {
    // Run code when API level lower than 21
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You should try this:**

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
    startscan();
}
else
{
   startlescan();
}
```